# undertow proxy dumping request and response bodies

Tags: java, undertow

To use undertow as a proxy server, which tracks all traffic (required for debugging purposes), I'm currently using a snippet like this:

```
Undertow.builder()
    .addHttpListener(8080, null)
    .setHandler(
        Handlers.requestDump(
            Handlers.proxyHandler(new SimpleProxyClientProvider(targeUri))
        )
    )
.build().start();
```

This already dumps all request and response headers. What I am searching for is a way to dump the request and response bodies, too. Any ideas of how to achieve that in combination with the ProxyHandler?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no easy way for dumping request and response bodies, you need to implement a handler yourself.
There is a light-weight framework which contains this functionality to dump request and response bodies, you can take a look at it as a reference or use it. [light-4j cross-cutting concerns](https://www.networknt.com/concern/), this contains the dump feature, but you need to consider how to inject to your code or write your own.
But to dump response may cause some performance issue, I suggest to use it carefully.